# Solving $(f'(x))^2 = f(x)f''(x)$ with boundary conditions.

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> Let $f$ be a continuous real-valued function such that $$(f'(x))^2 = f(x)f''(x).$$ Suppose $f(0) = 1$ and $f^{(4)} (0) = 9$. Find all possible values of $f'(0)$.

I have this question in my book of problems and I'm not sure how to conquer it! Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: $f^4$ is 4th derivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this: Take the derivative for both sides twice. First time:
$$ 2f'(x)f''(x)=f'(x)f''(x)+f(x)f'''(x) $$
to get
$$ f'(x)f''(x)=f(x)f'''(x). $$
Second time:
$$ (f''(x))^2+f'(x)f'''(x)=f'(x)f'''(x)+f(x)f^{(4)}(x) $$
or
$$ (f''(x))^2=f(x)f^{(4)}(x). $$
Setting $x=0$ in this equation to get $ (f''(0))^2=f(0)f^{(4)}(0)$ and using the conditions, you will get $(f''(0))^2=9$ or $f''(0)=\pm 3$. Thus
$$ (f'(0))^2=f(0)f''(0)=\pm 3 $$
from which you can get $f'(0)=\pm\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: So its just those two answers?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: Although the calculations are more complicated compared to the other hint, it's nice that you don't have to worry about division by zero.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: rewrite as

$$\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = \frac{f'(x)}{f''(x)}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:
 $f'(x)= \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$

$f''(x)= \frac{f'(x)-f'(a)}{x-a}$

etc. Given that the $f''''(0) = 9$, what is the least possible degree of $f(x)$?
Use this with the mean value theorem.

Comment: What is a degree of $f$?

Comment: Not sure how to use the mean value theorem

Comment: Note that $f$ is necessarily not a polynomial.